# Is there an R package equivalent for the win32com module from Python?

Tags: python, r, win32com

The Python module win32com allows to control local applications from inside a python script. It is possible to mimick user input such as input text, click buttons and so on.

My final goal is to start a program put in some text, click a button and the close this program completetely remotely.

I was unable so far to find anything remotely similar to this module for R. Is it even possible to do such a thing from inside an R script? Are there any specific packages and/or training documentation to do such a thing in R?

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with win32com; but a search on CRAN lead me to https://github.com/ChiHangChen/KeyboardSimulator
perhaps this is sufficient ?
also, R has a lot of interop with Python so potentionally R can drive Python to drive whatever ... ( package `reticulate`)

There is : http://www.statconn.com/documentation.html
but note that rcom was removed from CRAN due to license issues; so perhaps verify with your companies legal team that it wont cause you problems if using this with your work.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The KeyboardSimulator package seems to actually perform those actions, and from what I understood I might get difficult to guarantee the mouse is actually in the correct position before clicking a button. And it would make it impossible to work at the same time on the same machine, i think

The win32com package allows to click buttons or trigger reactions basically by a sort of id similar to how selenium is often used to control web browsers. so in a manner similar to clickbtton(thisprogram$button[5]).

Comment: I thought about using reticulate and it might end up the only way, but I would like to stay as much in R as possible, since I am not that experienced with Python. Especially since I would like to share this function with other coworkers which would probably be able to modify the script to their needs in R but probably not so much if it required adapting the underlying Python code